# Getting function from four points

Tags: exponential-function, graphing-functions, binary, hyperbolic-functions

I'm facing this problem I can't solve myself. I've got four points on a cartesian place, and I would like to find the function that equates them.
Coords are:

```
A(0.25;5)
B(0.5;3)
C(1;2)
D(2;1.5)
```

Is there any way to find the function that associates them?

**Background**
This is the problem: suppose you are a binary trader with a current balance of \$1000. Winning calls are rewarded with a 50% rate, which means you're going to get \$150 if you win a call where you've bet $100.
Your current target is \$1001: you want to find the amount of money you have to bet that will ensure to get to \$1001 if a winning call is placed.
It's easy to find the amount to "invest" using this formula:

```
x = (o-b)/r
```

where `x` is the amount of money you have to bet, `o` is your target (\$1001), `b` is your current balance (\$1000) and `r` is the interest (50%, thus 0.5).
In this case, `x = 2`: if \$2 are bet on a winning call, you'll earn \$1 achieving your goal.
It's easy to see that the higher the interest, the lower is the investment needed. Now, imagine you lose your first bet but your target is still \$1001. Using the above formula, the schema is the same and this time you have to bet \$6. The third time it will be \$18. Which means every time you lose a bet, your `x` will become three times your current bet, this with `r = 50%`.
With `r = 100%`, instead, the growth rate is only 2 (\$1, \$2, \$4...).
Here comes the chart:

```
A(0.50;3)
B(1;2)
...
```

I would like to have a function that will output the growth rate for any `r`. So that, for example, I will know what will be the growth rate with `r = 73%`.

I hope I was clear!
**Thank you**!

Comment: Are you looking for the interpolating cubic?  Obviously there are infinitely many functions passing through those four points.

Comment: The cubic is $-4 x^3 + 15 x^2 - 17.5 x + 8.5$.  Easy to compute...see [Lagrange Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).  Implemented in Wolfram Alpha as [InterpolatingPolynomial[(.25,5),(.5,3),(1,2),(2,1.5)]](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=InterpolatingPolynomial%5B(.25,5),(.5,3),(1,2),(2,1.5)%5D).

Comment: Note:  I was just responding to the first part of the question, didn't read the rest of it.

Comment: @lulu Honestly, I don't know! I thought there was a limited number of functions passing through those points. If you read the background, I guess you will understand the matter. Thank you!

Comment: Just read it.  I think you are just looking for $F(r)=1+\frac 1r$. If $r=.5$ we get $F(.5)=3$.  If $r=.73$ we get $F(r)=2.369863014$.  Easy to check that this goes through all four of your points.

Comment: @lulu Great, thanks for your time! Have a good day.

Comment: I just posted the calculation below.  It wasn't obvious to me that the ratio was constant over the bets.  I am sure there is an intuitive argument for that, but as I couldn't see it right away I thought it was worth posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g$ be the initial goal, in dollars.  Thus if you have $1000$ and want to get to $1001$, $g=1$.  Let $b_i$ denote the $i^{th}$ bet.  We have $$b_1=\frac gr$$

What is $b_2$?  Well, assuming you lost the first round then your new goal is $g+b_1$ since you need to recoup that loss.  It follows that $$b_2=\frac {g+b_1}r$$

To get the ratio, we compute  $$\frac {b_2}{b_1}=\frac {g+b_1}r \times \frac rg=\frac {g+b_1}g=1+\frac {b_1}g=\boxed {1+\frac 1r}$$

Let this be denoted $\lambda_r$.  We claim that $b_n=\lambda_r^{n-1}b_1$.  We've shown this for $n=1,2$.  Assume it holds up to $b_{k-1}$.  Assuming you have lost the first $k-1$ bets your new goal is $$g+b_1+\cdots +b_{k-1}=g+b_1\times (1+\lambda_r+\cdots + \lambda_r^{k-2})=g+b_1\times \frac {\lambda_r^{k-1}-1}{\lambda_r-1}$$

It follows that your next bet, $b_k$ must be $$b_k=\frac 1r \times \left(g+b_1\times \frac {\lambda_r^{k-1}-1}{\lambda_r-1}\right)=b_1+b_1\lambda_r^{k-1}-b_1=b_1\lambda_r^{k-1}$$  and we are done.

Comment: Clear! Thank you very much.